# set checkbox state to true in java server faces if the value is null or true

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have following code:

```html
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{dataSource.isRelevant}" 
                         styleClass="stateful"
                         style="padding: 0 10px 5px 10px;">
    <p:ajax event="change"
            process="@this"
            listener="#{dataSourceController.onChangeRelevantFilter(dataSource)}" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

I need to change #{dataSource.isRelevant} value so that checkbox state is set true if it is either null or true

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that `dataSource.isRelevant` is a capital B `Boolean`?

if so just change your Java code getter to this...

```java
public Boolean getIsRelevant() { 
   if (isRelevant == null) {
      return Boolean.TRUE;
   }
   return isRelevant;
}
```